# Making RelitiveLayouot view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android so I spent hours of trying to make this look like this in **code**. Could someone help on this ?  [image]

Here is my try :

```
RelativeLayout photo = new RelativeLayout(this);
        photo.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, densityToPixels(80)));
        photo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        allphotos.addView(photo);

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textView1.setText("IDasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfd");

        photo.addView(textView1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
        photo.addView(img);

        ImageView del_img = new ImageView(this);
        img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
        photo.addView(del_img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you do all that in code? Use xml. If you need the view constructed from xml use `View.inflate` passing your xml to it.

Comment: More detailed : i'm making list of photos. every time i take a picture  it puts it down using this way. So i found it most simple way to do that.

Comment: Then use ListActivity and make your ListAdapter's getView return (or reuse) View.inflate(your_xml)

Comment: sounds complicated, is there an example you know ?

Comment: This one seems similar to what you are doing http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: i tried smth like this. But couldn't find a way to append photos into list view after i take it

Comment: In your ListAdapter's getView you find a view that should hold the photo, using findViewById, then do setImageDrawable or similar on that view passing the photo to it

Comment: but how may i insert new line, with new photo after taking it ?

Comment: You could find it useful to read on a bit on Adapters in Android.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to do that in code...
Just use a TextView and add two compound drawables to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_left"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_rite"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**[EDIT]**

To set the compounds in code:

1 - You don't need these lines in the TextView definition, anymore:

```
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_left"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_rite"
```

2 - You need to set the drawables in code:

```
// given that you retrieved your TextView as txt and you retrieved your drawables as drwLeft and drwRite
// Parameter order: left, top, right, bottom 
txt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drwLeft, null, drwRite, null);
```

Comment: I need to insert photo captured after i take it. Is it possible? how may i change this code ?

Comment: but how.. ? i really don't know